# Selectively Combine several dataframes based on conditions in each dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, iteration, list-comprehension, vectorization

I have three different time based dataframes with 10s of thousands of data points.

```
df1['time']  = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
df1['data1'] = 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
```

---

```
df2['time']  = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 
df2['data2'] = a, b, c, d, e
```

---

```
df3['time']  = 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
df3['data3'] = z, y, x, w, v
```

---

I want to combine these dataframes into 1 dataframe only where they have the same time point existing. In the above dataframes only time 3 and 5 exist concurrently across all three so merge those data points into the final dataframe.

```
df4['time']  = 3, 5
df4['data1'] = 0, 0
df4['data2'] = b, c
df4['data3'] = z, x
```

---

I've been trying to avoid iterating over the dataframes with if statements because of the numerous data points and the answer in [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) from cs95 basically saying to avoid iterating if possible.

Am I stuck iterating through the dataframes or is there vectorization/list comprehension method I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `pd.merge`. I think of it like a SQL join, it works very similarly. In the example below I'm doing 2 merges (a.k.a. joins), first with `df1` to `df2` as an inner join on the time column, then that merged dataframe is merged with `df3` using inner join on time again.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,2,3,4,5], 'data1': [1,0,0,1,0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,3,5,7,9], 'data2': ['a','b','c','d','e']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'time': [3,4,5,6,7], 'data3': ['z','y','x','w','v']})
df4 = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='time').merge(df3, how='inner', on='time')
df4
Out[211]: 
   time  data1 data2 data3
0     3      0     b     z
1     5      0     c     x
```

`inner` join only keeps values that exist in both dataframes. the `on` field indicates which column(s) need to match to join.

Notice that the final result will include `data1`, `data2`, and `data3` from each of the columns, if you have columns that are the same name in the datasets and are not included in `on` then they will be renamed with `_df1`, `_df2`, `_df3` respectively.

Comment: This is the first time I've asked anything on stack overflow, I'm impressed with how quick and detailed of a response you gave. And it appears you edited my original question with formating clarity for others? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want the intersection of `time` in all three DataFrames, which can be handled by doing inner merge on `'time`. By default, `merge` performs inner merge, so you can simply use:

```
out = df1.merge(df2, on='time').merge(df3, on='time')
```

Output:

```
   time  data1 data2 data3
0     3      0     b     z
1     5      0     c     x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.concat` too:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,2,3,4,5], 'data1': [1,0,0,1,0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,3,5,7,9], 'data2': ['a','b','c','d','e']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'time': [3,4,5,6,7], 'data3': ['z','y','x','w','v']})

pd.concat([df.set_index('time') for df in [df1, df2, df3]],
          axis=1,
          join='inner').reset_index()
```

It gives:

```
   time  data1 data2 data3
0     3      0     b     z
1     5      0     c     x
```